# UWP ListView item template reuse previous item template

Tags: xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I just started to develop application on UWP. I got a problem that I have a ListView which DataTemplate is a UserControl

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemCustomStyle}">               
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <items:FeedItem DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,8"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Then I set datasource to ListView.

Those items rendered well but after a few items, they starting using previous item template somehow. I couldn't understand. Have anyone met this trouble and known how to fix it? Thanks very much.

Comment: what do you mean with "previous item template"?

Comment: @GeertvdC Sample: There's a lot of item in my ListView right? After scrolling about 10 items, the 11th items have exactly template like the first item although the content (data context) of that item is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

The ListViews default ItemsPanelTemplate has an ItemsStackPanel which uses virtualization. The idea is to have only those items in memory/rendered which are shown right now or easily reachable by scrolling. You can read more on this topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alainza/archive/2014/09/04/listview-basics-and-virtualization-concepts.aspx).

If you actually want to stop using any virtualization techniques you just have to define your own ItemsPanel. Like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```